# Ag-grid cell rendering to check for conditions

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display the values from database.Using cellRendering to check for conditions if there is no data i should display No Data else with data.
But i see only blank when there is data.How to bind the data to the grid if there is data.

```
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 150, cellRenderer: athleteCellRendererFunc},
    {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90},
     ];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    angularCompileRows: true
};

 function athleteCellRendererFunc(row) {
        if(row.data.athlete == null)
        {
           return '<span ng-bind="data.athlete">No Data</span>';
        }
        else
        {
           return '<span ng-bind="data.athlete"></span>';
        }
}
```

Comment: `ag-grid` or `ng-grid`?

Comment: Hi Ramesh it's ag-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
return '<span>' + data.athlete + '</span>';
```

`cellRenderer` simply expects the final HTML template to be returned.